# Solving set of equations with separate sides

Tags: calc

In the `calc`, how can I solve set of equations where I have the two sides of the equations in separate stack entries? For example, the current stack looks like this:

```
2:  [x, y, z]

1:  [1, 2, 3]
```

(I represent a set of equations x=1, y=2, z=3 by this.)

How can I solve this set of equations without having to manually rewrite the equations into one entry?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can press <kbd>`</kbd> to edit one of the sides in algebraic mode.